# Add new fields as an array in the same document without override the old ones in Firestore using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add new fields in a document that related to the logged in user (same UID)
to create a new document with the same UID as the user's UID I use the following:

```
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'data');

// submit function to add data
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        const uid = user.uid;
        try {
            // overrides the data
            await setDoc(doc(collectionRef, uid), {
                food: food,
                quantity: quantity,
            })

            alert("Data added successfully")
        } catch (error) {
            alert(`Data was not added, ${error.message}`)
        }
    }, [])
}
```

For add more fields to the array, I use the following:

```
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'data');

// submit function to add data
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        const uid = user.uid;
        try {
            await updateDoc(doc(collectionRef, uid), {
                food: arrayUnion(food),
                quantity: arrayUnion(quantity),
            })
            
            alert("Data added successfully")
        } catch (error) {
            alert(`Data was now added, ${error.message}`)
        }
    }, [])
}
```

the complete code:

```
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'data');

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        const uid = user.uid;
        try {
            // overrides the data - ???
            await setDoc(doc(collectionRef, uid), {
                food: food,
                quantity: quantity,
            })
       
            // add more fields to the array
            await updateDoc(doc(collectionRef, uid), {
                food: arrayUnion(food),
                quantity: arrayUnion(quantity),
            })

            alert("Data added successfully")
        } catch (error) {
            alert(`Data was now added, ${error.message}`)
        }
    }, [])
}
```

I can add more fields with the updateDoc() function, but if I will not comment or delete the setDoc() function after creating the new document, it will override the fields inside the document.

screenshot of the DB (Firestore):
I can add more fields only if I comment the setDoc() function after the doc first created

[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPFCv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create-or-update the document, you can use `{ merge: true }`:

```
await setDoc(doc(collectionRef, uid), {
    food: food,
    quantity: quantity,
}, { merge: true }) //
```

Also see the second code snippet in the documentation on [setting a documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

Comment: Your solution helped me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `onAuthStateChanged()` observer runs every time the user's auth state changes and then the `set()` will overwrite the existing document removing any existing data. You can try using `merge` option that won't delete rest of the fields as shown below:

```
const docRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid)

await setDoc(docRef, { food, quantity }, { merge: true })
```

This will still however overwrite the 'food' and 'quantity' arrays with the new value that you provide. So it might be best to use `setDoc()` only once after users registers in your application and use `updateDoc` thereafter.

---

Alternatively, you can also unsubscribe from the listener as shown below:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    // process data
    unsub();
  })
}
```

The handler might still trigger again if auth state changes before your processing is complete. You should use `onAuthStateChanged()` when the web app loads for the first time and then redirect user to different pages based on their auth state. Once you confirm that user is logged in then you can simply use the following to get current user:

```
const user = auth.currentUser; 

if (user) {
  // update document. 
}
```